# Pipe skips sleep. Writes multiple strings

Tags: c, pipe

I have this code which is supposed to write these three statements to a pipe and the parent must output whatever is in the pipe with a timestamp. These strings have to come singularly and in order.

```
int main(){
seedRandGen();
int k, pipes[2], pID, buflen;
char buff[BUFLEN + 1];
if(pipe(pipes) == 0){
    pID = fork();
    while(1){
        if(pID == 0){
            //CHILD
            //k = read(pipes[PIPEIN],buff,BUFLEN);
            const char *m1 = {"Breathing gas levels are adjusted."};
            const char *m2 = {"Light and Temperature levels are adjusted."};
            const char *m3 = {"Navigation adjustment made correctly."};
            sleep(getRandInt(3));
            k = write(pipes[PIPEOUT],m1,strlen(m1));
            sleep(getRandInt(6));
            k = write(pipes[PIPEOUT],m2,strlen(m2));
            sleep(getRandInt(3));
            k = write(pipes[PIPEOUT],m3,strlen(m3));
            //
            //  
        }
        else if(pID < 0){
            //FAILED TO FORK
            printf("Unable to open pipe. Everyone is dead. Good job.\n");
        }
        else{
            //PARENT
            if(!printed){
                printf("[%s]: %s\n", printTime(), "Spaceship Management System Start");
                printed = 1;
            }
            k = read(pipes[PIPEIN],buff,sizeof(buff));
            buff[k] = 0;
            printf("[%s]: %s\n",printTime(),buff);
        }
    }
}
close(pipes[PIPEIN]);
close(pipes[PIPEOUT]);
return 0;
}
```

With `seedRandGen()` and `getRandInt()` serving as functions that output what you would expect. The pipe is supposed to output only one string at a time, from m1 to m3. However, the output tells a different story:

```
[2015-04-28 11:43:12]: Breathing gas levels are adjusted.
[2015-04-28 11:43:16]: Light and Temperature levels are adjusted.Navigation adjustment made correctly.
[2015-04-28 11:43:17]: Breathing gas levels are adjusted.Light and Temperature levels are adjusted.Navigation adjustment made correctly.Breathing gas levels are adjusted.
[2015-04-28 11:43:21]: Light and Temperature levels are adjusted.Navigation adjustment made correctly.
[2015-04-28 11:43:22]: Breathing gas levels are adjusted.Light and Temperature levels are adjusted.Navigation adjustment made correctly.
[2015-04-28 11:43:24]: Breathing gas levels are adjusted.
[2015-04-28 11:43:25]: Light and Temperature levels are adjusted.
[2015-04-28 11:43:26]: Navigation adjustment made correctly.
[2015-04-28 11:43:28]: Breathing gas levels are adjusted.
[2015-04-28 11:43:31]: Light and Temperature levels are adjusted.Navigation adjustment made correctly.
```

At some points, more than one string is written into the pipe,as if the child had skipped a sleep. I don't know how to remedy this. What should I do?

Comment: Presumably `getRandInt()` can return 0, which means you'd get two writes in quick succession.  The "protocol" on the pipe needs to account for this.  For example, for each message you could send the length first, then the string.  When you read, read the length, then that number of bytes.  That way the reading side knows the boundaries of the messages.

Comment: That is precisely the problem I had. I fixed the getRandInt function and it works.